# Returning a generic width std_logic_vector filled with 0s to output

Tags: generics, vhdl

So I am going crazy trying to figure this out. I have an ALU that has a generic width, and I have every operation for the ALU working but I can not get it to return simply 0 for the empty operation slots.

The key for the assignment is to use the std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned packages. I have another ALU setup using numeric_std package and it is correctly sending the 0 for other operations.

Here is the code that works for numeric_std package:

```
when C_EMPTY1 =>
  temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned'(resize("0",WIDTH)));
  output <= temp;
```

And here is what I'm trying to do with the ALU that isn't working:

```
when C_EMPTY2 =>
  temp := std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(0, WIDTH));
  output <= temp;
```

For the ALU that isn't working it keeps returning the operation result for the previous operation.

Sorry here's how they are declared:

```
variable temp : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
output : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
```

Here's the whole program:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity alu_sla is
    generic (
        WIDTH : positive := 16
    );
    port (
        input1 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        input2 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        sel : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        output : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        overflow : out std_logic
    );
 end alu_sla;

-- Define an ALU using std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned
architecture STR of alu_sla is

    constant C_ADD : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    constant C_SUB : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0001";
    constant C_MULT : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0010";
    constant C_AND : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0011";
    constant C_OR : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0100";
    constant C_XOR : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0101";
    constant C_NOR : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0110";
    constant C_NOT_IN1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0111";
    constant C_SHIFTL1_IN1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1000";
    constant C_SHIFTR1_IN1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1001";
    constant C_SWAP_HIGHLOW_IN1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :=         
    "1010";
    constant C_REVERSE_BITS_IN1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := 
    "1011";
    constant C_EMPTY1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1100";
    constant C_EMPTY2 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1101";
    constant C_EMPTY3 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1110";
    constant C_EMPTY4 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1111";




    function Reverse (x : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is 
        alias alx  : std_logic_vector (x'length - 1 downto 0) is x; 
        variable y : std_logic_vector (alx'range); 
        begin 
            for i in alx'range loop 
                y(i) := alx (alx'left - i); 
            end loop; 
        return y; 
        end;

   function CheckMultSize (x : std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
        begin
            for i in WIDTH to WIDTH*2-1 loop
                if(x(i) = '1') then
                    return '1';
                end if;
            end loop;
        return '0';
    end;


begin -- STR

    process(input1, input2, sel)
        variable temp : std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        variable temp_add : std_logic_vector(WIDTH downto 0);
        variable temp_mult : std_logic_vector((WIDTH*2-1) downto 0);

    begin

        --defaults
        overflow <= '0';

        case sel is
            when C_ADD =>   
                temp_add := conv_std_logic_vector(unsigned(input1), 
                            WIDTH+1) + 
                            conv_std_logic_vector(unsigned(input2), 
                            WIDTH+1);
                output <= temp_add(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
                overflow <= temp_add(WIDTH);

            when C_SUB =>
                temp := std_logic_vector(unsigned(input1)) - 
                        std_logic_vector(unsigned(input2));
                output <= temp;

            when C_MULT =>
                temp_mult := std_logic_vector(unsigned(input1)) * 
                             std_logic_vector(unsigned(input2));


                if (CheckMultSize(temp_mult) = '1') then
                    overflow <= '1';
                else
                    overflow <= '0';
                end if;

                output <= temp_mult(WIDTH-1 downto 0);

            when C_AND =>
                temp := input1 and input2;
                output <= temp;

            when C_OR =>
                temp := input1 or input2;
                output <= temp;

            when C_XOR =>
                temp := input1 xor input2;
                output <= temp;

            when C_NOR =>
                temp := input1 nor input2;
                output <= temp;

            when C_NOT_IN1 =>
                temp := not input1;
                output <= temp;

            when C_SHIFTL1_IN1 =>
                overflow <= input1(WIDTH-1);
                temp := std_logic_vector(shl(unsigned(input1), 
                        conv_unsigned(1, 1)));
                output <= temp;

            when C_SHIFTR1_IN1 =>
                temp := std_logic_vector(shr(unsigned(input1), 
                        conv_unsigned(1, 1)));
                output <= temp;

            when C_SWAP_HIGHLOW_IN1 =>
                temp := (input1(WIDTH/2-1 downto 0) & input1(WIDTH-1 
                        downto WIDTH/2));
                output <= temp;

            when C_REVERSE_BITS_IN1 =>
                temp := Reverse(input1);
                output <= temp; 

            when C_EMPTY1 =>
                temp := (others => '0');
                output <= std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(0, WIDTH));

            when C_EMPTY2 =>
                temp := std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(0, WIDTH));
                output <= temp;

            when C_EMPTY3 =>
                temp := std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(0, WIDTH));
                output <= temp;

            when C_EMPTY4 =>
                temp := std_logic_vector(conv_unsigned(0, WIDTH));
                output <= temp;

            when others => null;    
        end case;   
    end process;
end STR;
```

All I am trying to do is get the C_EMPTY cases to return 0 to the output, but I can't get it to do so.

Comment: what's wrong with `temp := (others => '0');`?  This is an aggregate with all elements set to '0', the subtype taken from context (the target on the left and side of the variable assignment).  (And your readers can't tell what should work or not without declarations).

Comment: Sorry I added the declarations. Also tried what you said, and it still wasn't flushing the previous operation output to 0.

Comment: Show an [mcve] with the means to reproduce a specific problem. What is this "flushing the previous operation output to 0" of which you write? You're asking your reading audience to guess what the heck is going on.

Comment: It seems that you are asking us to debug code, which you think is a solution to your initial issue. You should instead put your initial problem here, as what you think is the solution is clearly not working.

Comment: conv_unsigned suggests you're using the wrong libraries anyway.

Comment: I have to use those specific libraries, and I added all of the code for the program so everyone can see. All I want to do is return a std_logic_vector full of 0's to the output for the C_EMPTY cases.

Comment: The one making you use those packages (packages, not libraries: `IEEE` is the common library) is living in 1993... or before. The `numeric_std` package (and derivatives of it) has since then replaced them as official standardized package.

Comment: Your code is neither Minimal nor Complete. [Removing everything not associated with C_EMPTY1 thru C_EMPTY4 and adding a testbench to drive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs7zhuit67xfx0g/alu_sla_mcve.vhdl?dl=1) sel [shows that all 4 of those case statement choices provide all '0' values on output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyI3x.png). Your problem lies elsewhere. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.